# Notifications of exceptions for haxe/nme/flash

Tags: flash, haxe, nme

I'm using Haxe and NME and the flash target to create a .swf. How do I make sure that uncaught Exceptions are shown? Currently it seems they are just silently eaten up. I'm compiling with:

```
haxelib run nme build path/to/MyNmmlFile.nmml flash
```

I believe it is some flag I need to pass there, or something I need to set in the nmml file, but don't know what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add <haxeflag name="-debug" /> to your nmml. And use flashplayerdebug.